# Alternatives to Essbase

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, essbase

I have [Essbase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essbase) as the BI solution (for Predictive Analytics and Data Mining) in my current workplace. It's a really clunky tool, hard to configure and slow to use. We're looking at alternatives. Any pointers as to where I can start at?

Is **Microsoft Analysis Services** an option I can look at? **SAS** or any others?

Comment: Essbase is probably the fastest and most complete OLAP cube solution out there. What version are you on? What reporting tools are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Essbase focus and strenght is in the information management space, not in predictive analytics and data mining.

The top players (and expensive ones) in this space are SAS (with Enterprise Miner & Enteprise Guide combination) and IBM with SPSS.

Microsoft SSAS (Analysis Services) is a lot less expensive (it's included with some SQL Server versions) and has good Data Mining capabilities but is more limited in the OR (operations research) and Econometrics/Statistics space.

Also, you could use R, an open source alternative, that is increasing its popularity and capabilities over time, for example some strong BI players (SAP, Microstrategy, Tableau, etc.) are developing R integration for predictive analytics and data mining.

Answer (score 0):

Check www.kpionline.com , is a product cloud based in Artus. 
It has many dashboards, scenarios and functions prebuilt to do analysis.

Other tool than you could check is microstrategy. It has many functions to analysis.